# Python Facebook API - Insight/Engagement data?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

so I'm trying to use the [Facebook Python API](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to pull our engagement data (likes, shares etc, basically all the stuff under the "Insights" tab on the Facebook website).

I've managed to get a connection via the API and get the access token working fine, no issues there.

Absolutely no clue on how to start pulling data (either at post or page level) though, had a look through the documentation and a bit of googling about, no luck. Is there a command? Is it an incomplete API and I'm better off trying to work out a different language?

Any help hugely appriciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the status of the Facebook Python API you link to, and the [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/info) tag for Python SDK's show either (deprecated) or (unofficial). However, the [facebook-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-graph-api/info) tag page states:

> The Facebook Graph API is provided by the Facebook platform to interact with Facebook's social graph.

which should remain consistent, reliable, and up-to-date as it *is* the source and not some third-party developers. [The Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) is currently v2.9 and has a lot of up-to-date documentation, and the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is useful to practice queries.

Here's a simple Python script that gets JSON data from the graph api. It's only in Python2.x, but presents the basic idea, getting the user name, likes, link, etc. There are [many other fields and endpoints](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post) you can include and point to, I only tested `id`,`name`, `likes`, and `link` (I couldn't find `shares` (I'm not even sure what that would be, I'm not a facebook user) but I'm sure you can figure it out).

Only need an [access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) and modify to whatever version of Python you use.

```
import urllib2
import json

page_id = "Facebook" # any username or id
access_token = '<your_access_token>'

page_data = None

api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/"
fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+page_id+"?fields=id,name,likes,link&access_token="+access_token
try:
    api_request = urllib2.Request(fb_graph_url)
    api_response = urllib2.urlopen(api_request)

    try:
        page_data = json.loads(api_response.read())
    except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
        page_data = "JSON error"

except IOError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        page_data = e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        page_data = e.reason

# entire JSON response
print page_data # {u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/facebook/', u'likes': 187433459, u'id': u'20531316728', u'name': u'Facebook'}

print "Page Name: " + page_data['name']   # Facebook
print "Likes: " + str(page_data['likes']) # 187433459
print "Link: " + page_data['link']        # https://www.facebook.com/facebook/
```

Anyway, I hope this helps or gives you an idea.

Comment: Updated the code for Python3 and it works perfectly cheers! Messing around with the graph explorer is actually pretty simple once you know what you're doing, thanks!